Blur a background image in compose
I am trying to blur a background image.
I have a background image of office environment and I have added a background overlay to it. And its that background I want to blur and make it slightly transparent.
This is the image and as you can see the overlay background isn't blurred. I used to alpha to make it slightly transparent.

And this is the code I am trying to blur
@Composable
fun GradientBackground(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enableOverlay: Boolean = false,
    hasToolbar: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()) {
        /* this is the office picture */
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.splash), contentDescription = null)

        if(enableOverlay) {
            /* This is the box and the backgroud I would like to blur over the image and make it slighty transparent */
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        listOf(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.8f), Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.9f))),
                    )
                    .blur(16.dp)
            )
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .then(
                    if (hasToolbar) {
                        Modifier
                    } else {
                        Modifier.systemBarsPadding()
                    }
                )
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}


Does this answer your question? Blur in Jetpack Compose

I did add the blur but it didn't seem to have any effect. You can see in my above code

To blur the image, apply the blur modifier to the Image itself, not to the Box overlay.
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().blur(16.dp),
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.splash),
    contentDescription = null,
)

To make the overlay more transparent, decrease the value of alpha.

Is it a way to blur partially? A mean half of the image for example.

No, it'll blur the whole image.

Blur modifier does not work below Android 12. instead, my suggestion is just to export the image as blur from your design prototype and use it as a background.
